# the integral of a function $\frac{1}{u(x)}$

Tags: integration

What is the integral of this function :

$$\frac{1}{u(x)}$$

for exemple :

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{1-x}$$

Comment: Are you looking for an answer regarding some particular family of functions $u$? Else, this question seems too broad.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by family of functions, I just want how to calculate a such integral

Comment: There is no general formula for $\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}$ in terms, say, of $u(x)$ and $\int u(x)\,dx$. For your particular function, we can write down the answer directly, or more slowly by letting $u=1-x$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I taught that $-ln|u(x)|$ is the solution for $\int\frac{dx}{u(x)}$ because the solution for the exemple I gived is $-ln|1-x|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: if you have an integral of the form

$$\int_a^b \dfrac {f'(x)}{f(x)} \quad \text{or}\quad \int_a^b \frac{du}{u(x)}$$

Then the general form of the solution is $$\ln|f(x)| \Big|_a^b$$

In your example:

$$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{1-x}$$

Let $u(x) = f(x) = 1 - x$, $  f'(x) = -1 \implies $

then $$\int_a^b\frac{dx}{1-x}  = \int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = -\int_a^b \dfrac {(-1)}{1-x} dx= -\ln|1 - x|\Big|_a^b$$

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what sort of function $u(x)$ is. For instance, if you have $u(x)$ as a polynomial, then you can express $u(x)$ in the form
$$
u(x) = a\prod_{n} (x-x_n)^{\alpha_n}
$$
for integer $\alpha_n>0$, In which case, you can then express $\frac1{u(x)}$ in a form
$$
\frac1{u(x)} = \sum_n \sum_{i=1}^{\alpha_n}\frac{k_{n,i}}{(x-x_n)^i}
$$
by applying partial fraction. And this can then be integrated to get
$$
\int \frac1{u(x)}dx = \sum_n \left(k_{n,1}\ln(x-x_n)-\sum_{i=2}^{\alpha_n}\frac{k_{n,i}}{(i-1)(x-x_n)^{i-1}}\right)+C
$$
Some other functions can also be integrated nicely. For instance, if $u(x)=\cos(x)$, then you have
\begin{align}
\int \frac1{\cos(x)}dx &= \int \frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}dx\\
&=\int \frac{du}{1-u^2} & (u=\sin(x))\\
&=\int \frac{\sec^2(y)}{\sec^2(y)}dy & (u=\tanh(y))\\
&= y+C = \tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))+C
\end{align}
It can also be shown that this is equivalent to
$$
\int \frac1{\cos(x)}dx = \log|\tan(x)+\sec(x)|+C
$$
However, if $u(x)=e^{x^2}$, then there's no nice expression for the integral of $\frac1{u(x)}$ using elementary functions. And there's no single method of evaluating integrals of that form - it depends on the function.

Comment: In the case of $u(x)=e^{x^2}$, there's no nice expression for $\int u(x)dx$, either.  It's roughly the same thing, because $\dfrac{1}{u(x)}=u(ix)$, so you could actually express $\int\dfrac{1}{u(x)}dx$ in a simple way in terms of $\int u(x)dx$, roughly speaking.  Another example is $u(x)=\ln(x)$, where $\int u(x)dx$ has a simple formula but $\int\dfrac{1}{u(x)}$ is not elementary.